# Stop Visual Studio Code from creating a symbols.json file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

For some reason (perhaps it's since I installed and removed a python extension, or it's just since the latest update) Visual Studio Code keeps creating a **"symbols.json"** file inside the **.vscode** folder in every project.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening? It isn't mentioned in the official documentation. I have already disabled all extensions.

After deleting the file manually, it keeps reappearing. The contents of the file are:

```
{"symbols":{},"files":{}}
```

I can't find the setting to remove this behavior. It's not in settings.json.

Comment: I get this file as well all the time now. In my case it contains all classes and all files (I use vscode "Typescript Task" functionality)

Comment: I found the cause: it's one of the installed extensions. I immediately removed it and now symbols.json is gone. I don't want all kinds of extra files in my project just for the IDE.

Comment: now as you mentioned extensions: I also have disabled 2 Typescript related extensions: `TsTools` and `TypeScript Toolbox`.  Must be one of them..